# ASP.NET MVC - RenderPartial with dynamic model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic

We have a ViewModel with a collection of `Widget<dynamic>`:

```
public class Widget<T>
{
    public string ViewName { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

In our View we loop through the collection of widgets and call `Html.Partial`.

```
@foreach (var widget in Model) {
    @Html.Partial(widget.ViewName, widget)
}
```

This works *providing* the partial has a dynamic model or a model of `Widget<dynamic>`.

However, I would like intellisense within the partial view so I give my view a model of the appropriate widget data type e.g:

```
@model Widget<string>
```

Unfortunately this throws an exception as `@Html.Partial` is casting the dynamic model as System.Object.

Aside from manually casting the widget again within the partial, is there a way to call `Html.Partial` without having the dynamic model cast as an object?

Comment: If you know that `T` is a `string`, why do use `dynamic`?

Comment: We don't know that `T` is a `string`. The main ViewModel contains a collection of widgets that could be `Widget<string>`, `Widget<SomeModel>` etc. Only the Partial "knows" what *should* be passed to it.

Comment: If you use T then there is no need for dynamic. Your view model should have a collection of Widget<T>s and not Widget<dynamic>

Comment: @Mark, I should have been more explicit - the view model will contain widgets of **different** types.

Comment: @Ben I think I see the problem now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a interface and all dynamic object type widgets must implements the interface,  I did the same a time ago and worked smooth

Simple example with render: (it's just a quick example you must complete)

```
    public interface IWidget{

     public System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString RenderMyWidget(HtmlHelper helper);

}




public class ContenidoWidgets : IWidget{

    private String Controller { get; set; }

    private String Action { get; set; }

    private Object Parms {get; set; }

    public ContenidoWidgets(String controller, String action, Object parms)
    {

        this.Controller = controller;
        this.Action = action;
        this.Parms = parms;

    }

    public System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString RenderMyWidget(HtmlHelper helper){

        return System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(helper, this.Action, this.Controller, this.Parms);

    }
```

the view....

```
@model IWidget

@model.RenderMyWidget(this.html);
```

Comment: Ah, so you're delegating the responsibility of rendering the widget, to the widget. I'll give it a shot.